# how to zip a file in hdfs without pulling it into local file system

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

is it possible to zip a file in hdfs without pulling it into the local system drive? I usually do this by doing an `hadoop fs -get filename` and then zipping that via linux zip command...but can I do this in hdfs itself?

Comment: Do you want to end up with a zipped file that's in HDFS, or on your local fs?

Comment: I guess either is fine...ideally like to end up in the local fs but would like to know how to do it both ways just in case...

Answer (score 1):

You can create a MapReduce job using Identity Mapper (the output is the same than the input) and not reducer; configuring the Mapper output to be compressed. I want to suggest use GZip or LZO instead Zip format, but only you know your requirements.